# Why use Open Telemetry Logging in Kubernetes dotnet service?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, open-telemetry, observability

I have a dotnet web api that has been deployed to a Kubernetes cluster.
I see a lot of experienced folks suggesting using Open Telemetry SDK with Console exporter instead of dotnet inbuilt logging logger.

However, when I configured (see the configuration below) the Otel SDK logger, I see bunch of data on the console logs even for a single log line.
Not sure what purpose does it serve.
Can somebody explain?

```
builder.Services.AddLogging((loggingBuilder) => loggingBuilder
            .AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
                options.AddConsoleExporter())
            );
```